# Creating interactive map on web page

Tags: qgis, javascript, web-mapping, software-recommendations, geodjango

I am working on a website using Django. A central component of this website will be a map page with accompanying functionality. I was planning on using JavaScript to render the map and use AJAX to get data from my server for the usage of the map. I am not sure at the best way to implement the map. I know there a number of Web GIS softwares that have nice prebuilt functionality. The problem is that I want to use my own maps (created from QGIS) and data. I am not sure how to configure them to use my shapefiles for the map. The other option is to use HTML Canvas. I could easily get something to work but I would rather have the functionality of an existing Web GIS software to use.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

Most frameworks will require your data to be  hosted as some type of map service, feature service, or tile service.  Map services return images of the map layer in response to a request that includes the boundary box of the client side map.  Feature services return geometry as json which the client renders as graphics over a base map.

If your data is small enough, you can avoid running a spatial server by converting it to geo json and including it as static content in your application.  Many of the client frameworks have libraries for reading geojson and rendering it as graphics.

I'd suggest looking into leaflet which is a nice lightweight js mapping API that makes it easy to render geojson as map graphics layers.

https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/

https://codepen.io/alexkaessner/pen/RxrNva

Here is a web service that recieves a zipped shapefile (POST request) and returns json that can be used to generate graphics.  I'm not sure if it's licensed for free use in production but it might be helpful in experimenting with client side code and graphics rendering.

https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/features/generate?filetype=shapefile&publishParameters={"name":"testline","targetSR":{"latestWkid":3857,"wkid":102100},"maxRecordCount":1000,"enforceInputFileSizeLimit":true,"enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit":true}&f=json

Comment: I looked into leaflet. My problem is that I want to have my map rendered from a shapefile and then supply the data as geojsons or similar. Do you know if there is a way to do this. I plan to do a lot more research into this.

Comment: The most common way is to use a spatial server system (ArcGIS Server, MapServer, etc) which reads the shape file in response to a http request and returns results. If this isn't an option and you don't simply want to convert your shapefile to geojson for hosting as a static resource in the app,  I have written code that reads a shape file using netTopology Suite and return geojson, but this is quite involved.

Comment: Here is an example of a web service that accepts a zipped sharefile and returns json.  The service is hosted by esri and it may not be licensed for use in production but it might be helpful to experiment with...https://www.arcgis.com/sharing/rest/content/features/generate?filetype=shapefile&publishParameters={"name":"testline","targetSR":{"latestWkid":3857,"wkid":102100},"maxRecordCount":1000,"enforceInputFileSizeLimit":true,"enforceOutputJsonSizeLimit":true}&f=json

Comment: What I really want to do is have the user search a database and have the results display on my map. GreyHippo mentioned Qgis2web. I had come across that previously and it works nice for what I am trying to do. I was thinking I could use the leaflet api and make AJAX calls to add data to the map.

Answer (score 1):

To get a web map from Qgis use a Qgis plugin named Qgis2Web.  Qgis2web will take most of your data in the project and convert it to geojson files and will use Openlayers or Leaflet to make the web map files.

https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web

Comment: Yeah I am using that. I have my map as a Qgis2Web map. It is a proof of concept of what I want to do.

Comment: Qgis2web does have a search tool.